# What is groupItemMetaDataProvider in slickgrid?

Tags: slickgrid

Here is a code which sets the properties for dataview but what is groupItemMetaDataProvider?
,is it for rows or for columns?

dataView= new Slick.Data.DataView({
groupItemMetadataProvider: groupItemMetadataProvider,
inlineFilters: true,
rowHeight: 20
});

Answer (score 0):

It serves functionality about groups, their total rows, collapsing/expanding and so on.

Check `slick.groupitemmetadataprovider.js` file for more details.